# Can't find onboard NIC with windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, drivers

I'm trying to setup a windows server, but I can't seem to get it to install ethernet drivers :(
motherboard is ms-6743 chipset 82865g/pe/p(intel) 
The MSI drivers specifically for this motherboard are bad links. Not surprising... MSI is rarely helpful.
Sisoft Sandra doesn't see any network devices, and all of my leads to drivers have reported that there is no network adapter to install a driver for.
The light is ON on the mobo, the onboard setting in bios is ON and the computer worked just fine with a standard install of windows 7 about a month ago.

I don't know what to do :(

Answer (score 1):

That chipset uses an Intel 82562EZ on-board ethernet controller if I'm not mistaken.

[The drivers you need](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=1702&DwnldID=18720&lang=eng) are available from [Intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Ethernet+Components&ProductLine=Ethernet+Controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+82562EZ+Fast+Ethernet+Controller). Download them using another computer, transfer the installer and run it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try googling for the proper driver. See the detailed specs on where the LAN is coming from, if its from an intel chipset, then intel probably has drivers. Make sure you are using the proper drivers (32 or 64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

Consider finding another temporary NIC. USB-based or whathaveyou. Then fire up Windows Update.

Does Windows Update then find the driver for your onboard NIC?